# What does "I'm feeling lucky" button do?

Tags: google-search

I am using Google many years, but I still don't know what does "I'm feeling lucky" button,
and why it's placed there. Explain me .

Comment: Did you try using it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Earlier (when the changing button and Google Instant was not there), this button directly opened up the first search result from Google.

Later, if there is no search query in the Search Bar, this button opens up the Doodles page.

Now, Google has added another Easter egg. When you hover over the "I'am Feeling Lucky" button, it changes to some other. Upon clicking it, it takes you to another page with some relation to the text. Like "I'am feeling Doodley" takes you to Doodles page.

Answer (score 5):

It opens the first search result page.

Usually, Google search gives *n* number of results which you can click and open the URL of your wish.

#### I'm feeling lucky with Google Instant Disabled

Google's homepage includes a button labeled "I'm Feeling Lucky". When a user types in a search and clicks on the button the user will be taken directly to the first search result, bypassing the search engine results page. The thought is that if a user is "feeling lucky", the search engine will return the perfect match the first time without having to page through the search results.

#### I'm feeling lucky with Google Instant Enabled

When the user types the text and mouse over on it, it shows "I'm Feeling Lucky". By clicking on it, user will be landed directly on first search result.

Answer (score 1):

Now if you simply hover over the "I'm Feeling Lucky" it shows a variety of other labels like "I'm Feeling Trendy" ,"I'm Feeling Playfull"..etc and simply clicking on it takes you to a random page related to the label you clicked, which is powered by Google

Answer (score 0):

It supposed to do something related to your search, like if you put in gravity and hit I'm Feeling Lucky, everything falls to the bottom of the screen.  It's not working for me.

Comment: What you describe is not the main scope of the "I'm Feeling Lucky" button. What you found was probably one (of several) easter eggs that Google implements in their search.